# Por que será que o Firefox não tem suporte ao form type="time"?

Tags: html5

Testei esse type num form e ficou muito ruim, ele não aparece nenhum tipo de menu para modificar a hora. No navegador da Google aparece. Fica complicado pois todo tipo de formulário nunca rodará 100% em todos navegadores. Alguma solução?

Comment: O problema mesmo é com o tipo `datetime-local`, fica igual ao tipo `text`

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam datetime-local não foi implementado nem no FF nem no Safari (compatibilidade: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Browser_compatibility). Tecnlogias novas são assim, exigem testes, implementações em Alphas, Betas e etc. O motivo de não terem implementando é por possiveis limitações, tempo ou planejamento, aonde outras necessidade podem ser mais importantes no momento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme nesta **[documentação no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)** o Firefox até tem suporte ao `type`, porém não dispõe das setas ▲ e ▼. Creio também que a documentação esteja desatualizada, uma vez que o Firefox mais moderno (Quantum 59.0.2) as horas são no formato 24h, e não 12h como informa a documentação.

Esses tipos (não só o `type="time"`) variam muito de navegador para navegador, pois cada fabricante tende a renderizar da forma que acha melhor ao seu usuário, e não possuem padrões **[UI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_do_utilizador)** definidos.

Print do `input type="time"` no Firefox:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para contornar essas situações, você pode recorrer ao CSS + JavaScript para criar algo no mesmo estilo e padronizado, que será exibido igualmente em todos os navegadores.

Comment: Exato, vou ter de recorrer ao JavaScript pois não estou com problema só com o tipo type, pois como você mesmo disse, cada fabricante renderiza de uma forma. Obrigado!

Comment: Foi o corretor. Kkkk.

Answer (score 2):

No Chrome também não tem menu, o que tem são setas e uma especie de mascara no campo para digitar.

No Firefox desde a versão 57 (tanto no Firefox Desktop quanto Mobile) existe a mascara e as setas para controle do `time`, veja um print:

> [image: firefox]

Se o seu navegador é mais antigo que o 57 então é porque **seu Firefox esta desatualizado** no seu computador.

Segue lista de navegadores com suporte: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Se fala do menu realmente, deve ter notado no navegador Microsoft Edge ou nos navegadores mobile:

Edge:

> [image: input time edge]

Navegadores Android (provavelmente Chrome):

> [image: input time Android]

No Chrome Desktop só aparece isto:

[image: input time chrome desktop]

Comment: Vou atualizar o Firefox, deve ser isso. Obrigado.

Comment: Atualizei e mesmo assim não adiantou, ele não mostra nenhuma setinha, nenhuma caixinha, nada. Só os tracinhos.

Comment: @WillianMoscardi foi o que eu disse, setas não são menu, menu é só no Edge e Android.